# input loses binding Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I am having a very strange problem with Ember that I haven't had before. The scenario is quite a lot more complicated than I can outline here so I'll do my best to give a simplified version below.

I have a component which dynamically renders forms from a schema Ember.object(). Something like the below stored as `formSchema` on the component, where md-text-input is a normal text input field:

```
  [
    {
      component: "md-text-input",
      value: "some value here",
      label: "Text input"
    },
    {
      component: "md-number-input",
      value: "9",
      label: "Number input"
    }
  ]
```

The component template then looks like:

```
{{#each formSchema as |field|}}
  {{field.value}}
  {{component field.type value=field.value label=field.label}}
{{/each}}
```

The `formSchema` object is changed in the component which causes the form displayed to change.

The first form that renders, the binding works correctly and typing in the input field will update the `{{field.value}}`. However, once the `formSchema` updates the binding no longer works and although the input field shows the initial value, typing into it will not update `field.value`.

Any help is greatly appreciated as I can't seem to get my head around why Ember is losing this binding.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like it is something to do with some witchcraft I was doing in a component that this was extending from. Will go into more detail once I have looked at it, but is to do with registering a child component in the parent component, to send actions up (naughty I know)

Comment: I'm seeing similar voodoo: The initial observer fires when the component gets focus but after that the bindings are all broken.